# Store and recall command in MacOS terminal

Tags: macos

I am familiar with how to navigate through my command history in a MacOS Terminal window. What I really want however is to be able to store a command and recall it without having to navigate through the history. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: use an `alias` or write a little script and put it in your `bin` directory (which needs to be on your PATH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `alias`. See `man alias`. You can make this permanent by editing `~/.bashrc`

Also, you might like to read about making better use of [bash history](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps) - for example, did you know about the use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> or `!foo` or `!?foo?` where `foo` is part of a prior command?